# How to expand all items in a GtkTreeView at start

Tags: gtk, gtktreeview

Can any one tell me how to set tree view attribute so that all tree items can show up by default?

The first image shows what I get and the second image shows what I would like to get automatically, that is, to expand the `GtkTreeView` without clicking the expander.

[image: GtkTreeView without expanding the items, not what I want]
[image: GtkTreeView showing all items expanded, without clicking the expander to show <code>sd0</code> item]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You have not specified the language.  In C, you should call [gtk_tree_view_expand_all()](http://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkTreeView.html#gtk-tree-view-expand-all). In Python you should call `my_tree.expand_all()`

Comment: Thanks! gtk_tree_view_expand_all() is what I need!

Comment: If that answers your question, then should accept the answer :-)

Comment: I know, but system says I need wait 4 minutes then I can accept the answer..., Thanks!